# Is the sentence structure "because... and so" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, questions

According to the grammar I know, I only use either "because" or "so", but I do not use them in one sentence at the same time. I found that a translator always renders in this way. Sometimes the translator uses "because... and so," "not because...so," or "some say because... and so." My editing team are confused about that and don't know if it is a grammar error.  Is "**because**... **and so**" proper in written English?

Examples:

> "Throughout history there has been no mention of extra terrestrial
>   beings living on the planet. **Because** they do not appear to us, **and so**
>   many feel they do not exist."
>
> "And because she was young, and so damn clever and amusing and
>   wonderful, wherever she made her home, there would be some man who
>   would fall in love with her." (Crown of Midnight)
>
> "Finitude is implicit in being limited, therefore, because being
>   limited, and so coming to a stop, is itself part of a thing's ownmost
>   being." (The Opening of Hegei's Logic: From Being to Infinity)

A quick google search shows 339,000 instances and of which 279,000 in the 21st century (supposedly). I want to make sure is "**Because**...**and so**..." proper grammar?

Comment: The first example is incorrect; the second two are fine.

Comment: @Anonym Sentence fragments are rarely regarded as 'incorrect' per se nowadays. Here, admittedly, it's clumsy, and I'd prefer a colon before 'because', and a dash before 'and'. The greater fault is with the pseudo-logic of the statement. 'People rarely believe in dextrobopers because they never manifest.'

Comment: In the 2nd and 3rd examples, _and so_ is not the phrase. _so_ is modifying the phrase after it.

Comment: The second example is almost correct (at the very least it needs to ditch a comma).  But in that case "so" is being used as an intensifier (adverb) on "damn".  This is different from using "so" as a conjunction.  (The above translations are pretty badly mucked up.)

Comment: (The first example is badly mucked up due to its punctuation.  That needs to be cleaned up first.  Third example is awkward but sorta works.)

Comment: The first would make sense (to the extent that the subject matter does) if written "This is because they do not appear to us, and so many people feel they do not exist."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is incorrect because "and so" is rendered redundant by the usage of "because" (both are trying to explain the cause of the same thing). In the second and third examples, the "and so" is serving a different purpose from the because, and so both are necessary and acceptable in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in your first example:

"Because they do not appear to us, and so many feel they do not exist."

There are THREE conjunctions there to unite two clauses! You only need one!
"Because" is a subordinating conjunction, which means that "Many feel they do not exist" must be the main clause. "And" and "so" are both usually treated as coordinating conjunctions, though, which would mean both clauses are independent. Those things can't both be true.
BUT I think there's something else happening. I wonder if the intention was for one sentence instead of two:

"Throughout history there has been no mention of extra terrestrial beings living on the planet because they do not appear to us, and so many feel they do not exist."

It is possible that the word "so" is an adverb: because 1. they do not appear, and 2. so many people feel they do not exist. But I don't think so.
"They are never mentioned because they don't speak English, and so no one hires them."
One possible meaning for your example would be:

"Because extra terrestrial beings do not appear to us, there has been no mention of them living on the planet. Because there has been no mention of them living on the planet, many feel they do not exist."
OR
"Because extra terrestrial beings do not appear to us, many feel they do not exist. Because of this, there has been no mention of them living on the planet."

It is a very odd, unclear sentence, if you want to know!